# Writing a test to Spring boot REST API that retrieve data from a DB

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, integration-testing, spring-boot-test

I have a spring boot REST API with a GET method that returns data available in a DB. I am attempting to write an integration test to test this API method. I have configured the test to use the H2 database. I am trying to add some mock data to the database before the test is executed and see if the API retrieves that data. Following is the code I have written so far.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application-test.properties")
public class MetaControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Autowired
    private ProvinceDAO provinceDAO;

    @Transactional
    @Before
    public void addData () {
        Province southern = getProvinceEntity("Southern", "දකුණ", "தென்");
        provinceDAO.createEntity(southern);
        System.out.println(provinceDAO.findAll(Province.class).size());
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetProvinces() throws Exception {

        MvcResult result = mvc.perform(get("/meta/provinces"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().contentTypeCompatibleWith(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andReturn();
        System.out.println(result.getResponse().getContentAsString());


    }
}
```

However, when I run this code, I am getting an error saying "`org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: No transactional EntityManager available; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No transactional EntityManager available`"

I have also attempted using `@MockBean` instead of `@Autowired` to bind the `provinceDAO`. Even though this prevents the error, it does not persist the entity in the database.

How should I write my testcase to test my method here?

**Update:**

application-test.properties

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:h2:mem:test
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

Entity -> Province.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "w4a_province")
public class Province {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "province_name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "province_name_si")
    private String nameSi;

    @Column(name = "province_name_ta")
    private String nameTa;
    .
    .
}
```

GenericDAO.java

```
@Repository
public class GenericDAO<T> implements IGenericDAO<T> {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;


    @Override
    public Session getCurrentSession() {
        return this.em.unwrap(Session.class);
    }
    @Override
    public T findByPrimaryKey(Class<T> clazz, Object primaryKey) {
        return getCurrentSession().find(clazz, primaryKey);
    }


    @Override
    public List<T> findAll(Class<T> clazz) {
        DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(clazz);
        return criteria.getExecutableCriteria(getCurrentSession()).list();
    }


    @Override
    public T createEntity(T entity) {
        getCurrentSession().save(entity);
        return entity;
    }
```

ProvinceDAOImpl.java

```
@Repository
public class ProvinceDAOImpl  extends GenericDAO<Province> implements ProvinceDAO {
}
```

MetaController.java

```
@RestController
@PreAuthorize("permitAll()")
public class MetaController {

    private final MetaService metaService;


    @Autowired
    public MetaController(MetaService metService) {
        this.metaService = metService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/meta/provinces")
    public ResponseEntity<List<ProvinceDTO>> getProvinces() {
        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug("Retrieving list of provinces.");
        }

        List<ProvinceDTO> provinces =  metaService.getProvinces();
        return ResponseEntity.ok(provinces);
    }
}
```

MetaServiceImpl.java

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class MetaServiceImpl implements MetaService {

    private final ProvinceDAO provinceDAO;
    @Autowired
    public MetaServiceImpl(ProvinceDAO provnceDAO) {
        this.provinceDAO = provnceDAO;
    }

    public List<ProvinceDTO> getProvinces() {
        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug("Obtaining a list of provinces from database.");
        }
        List<Province> entities = provinceDAO.findAll(Province.class);
        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug("Converting province entities to dtos.");
        }
        List<ProvinceDTO> dtos = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < entities.size(); i++) {
            Province entity = entities.get(i);
            if (LocaleContextHolder.getLocale().getLanguage().equals(
                    GlobalConstants.LanguageIdentifiers.SINHALA_LANGUAGE_TAG)) {
                dtos.add(new ProvinceDTO(entity.getId(), entity.getNameSi()));
            } else if (LocaleContextHolder.getLocale().getLanguage().equals(
                    GlobalConstants.LanguageIdentifiers.TAMIL_LANGUAGE_TAG)) {
                dtos.add(new ProvinceDTO(entity.getId(), entity.getNameTa()));
            } else {
                dtos.add(new ProvinceDTO(entity.getId(), entity.getName()));
            }
        }
        return dtos;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please add the code for the `MetaController` and for `ProvinceDAO` and the content of `application-test.properties`

Comment: I updated the question with Controller, DAO and Entity code.

Comment: does your application work when you start it and manually access the endpoint with either curl or Postman? Can you also share `MetaService` please

Comment: I have added the MetaServiceImpl.java. I have tested the application endpoints with AdvancedRestClient chrome extension and it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to feed the database with the required data by placing a SQL script data-h2.sql  with insert queries at the test/resources folder. This prevented the requirement to use an EntityManager or a DAO.

Furthermore, I added the following property to the `application-test.properties` file.

```
spring.datasource.platform=h2
```

Answer (score 0):

In Order to test Rest Api You can try functional test as well as integration test.
You can prepare your own response formate as required and check whether the same is returned or else you can also verify whether the data from db is fine or not.Plz check the below example

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = FactsMain.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public abstract class BaseTest {
   protected MockMvc mvc;
   @Autowired
   WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

   protected void setUp() {
      mvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();
   }
   protected String mapToJson(Object obj) throws JsonProcessingException {
      ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
      return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(obj);
   }
   protected <T> T mapFromJson(String json, Class<T> clazz)
      throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {

      ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
      return objectMapper.readValue(json, clazz);
   }
}
```

In First test case i am forming the response format and trying to return the same and then validating the same.Here i don't need the db data so i have kept service as mock instead of auto wired.And used ObjectMapper for converting json to java and then java obj to json from base Test class.

```
public class PersonalDetailsControllerTest extends BaseTest {

    @MockBean
    private IPersonalService service;

    private static final String URI = "/api/personalDetails";

   @Override
   @Before
   public void setUp() {
      super.setUp();
   }

   @Test
   public void testGet() throws Exception {
      PersonalDetailsEntity entity = new PersonalDetailsEntity();
      List<PersonalDetailsEntity> dataList = new ArrayList<PersonalDetailsEntity>();
      FactsAdminResponse<PersonalDetailsEntity> dataResponse = new FactsAdminResponse<PersonalDetailsEntity>();

      entity.setId(1);
      entity.setName(“Anthony Holmes”);
      entity.setAge(26);
      entity.setCity(“Banglore”);
      entity.setCountry(“India”);

      dataList.add(entity);

      dataResponse.setData(dataList);

      Mockito.when(service.getBuildings()).thenReturn(dataList);

      RequestBuilder requestBuilder =  MockMvcRequestBuilders.get(URI)
                 .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

        MvcResult mvcResult = mvc.perform(requestBuilder).andReturn();
        MockHttpServletResponse response = mvcResult.getResponse();

        String expectedJson = this.mapToJson(dataResponse);
        String outputInJson = mvcResult.getResponse().getContentAsString();

        assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK.value(), response.getStatus());
        assertEquals(expectedJson, outputInJson);
   }
   }
```

In below case we are getting the actual data in json format as we are doing rest api call and then just validating the status apart from status you can also cross check the data

```
public class PersonalDetailsControllerTest extends BaseTest {

    private static final String URI = "/api/personalDetails";

   @Override
   @Before
   public void setUp() {
      super.setUp();
   }

 @Test
   public void getGet() throws Exception {

      MvcResult mvcResult = mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get(URL)
         .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)).andReturn();

      int status = mvcResult.getResponse().getStatus();
      assertEquals(200, status);
      String content = mvcResult.getResponse().getContentAsString();
      //you got the content in string format now you can also validate the data 

   }
```

Comment: The question I am having here is, how can I add some initial data to the DB, so I can verify that my API get method returns the actual data in the DB when I called the method. As far as I understand, in your 2nd example, you have added some data, but you have not persisted them in the DB.

Comment: In my second example I am not adding any data I am just making api call and validating the status. If you want to add data in db then make a post/save call first

Comment: My API don't have post functionality to this particular resource. It will be initially fed by running an sql script on the DB. The issue I am having is how to feed this data in to the test db

Comment: If you are using jpa Or hibernate then you can call save method on entity with your required data

Comment: That is when I get this "no transactional entity manager available" error

Comment: I updated the question with Controller, DAO and Entity code.